# "Un-const"-ing a type in D

Tags: templates, d

I'm trying to write a template named `Unconst` that would turn something like `const(int)` into `int`; in other words

```
Unconst!(const(int))
```

should give

```
int
```

I can't figure out how, though... any creative ideas for making this work?

(Extension: It would be great if the method could be extended to also work with `shared` and other type constructors.)

Comment: If this is just an exercise, great. Otherwise, if you want something like this for general use, I would check out the built-in `Unqual!()` template: http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_traits.html#Unqual

Comment: @Justin: Haha thanks. :) In fact, I actually remembered that there was something like that, and I figured out the solution by looking at the definition for `Unqual`. It doesn't exactly fit my needs by itself because I only wanted to remove one qualifier, but thanks for the link. :]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer myself...

```
template Unconst(T)
{
    static if (is(T U == const U))
        alias U Unconst;
}
```